# Windows move too fast using e.clientX

Tags: javascript

I am building a window resize feature. I have tried myself but when I try to grab and drag the handle the windows moves too quickly.

```js
(function () {
  const d = {};
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    const container = e.target.closest(".container");
    if (container != null && e.target.classList.contains("handle")) {
      d.el = container;
      d.div1 = container.children[0];
      d.handle = container.children[1];
      d.div2 = container.children[2];
      d.mouseStartX = e.clientX;
      d.elStartX = d.el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      d.handle.style.background = "rgb(100, 100, 100)";
      document.body.style.userSelect = "none";
      document.body.style.cursor = "e-resize";
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    if (d.el === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    d.div1.style.width =
      d.div1.offsetWidth + (e.clientX - d.mouseStartX) + "px";
  });
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    if (d.el === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    d.handle.style.background = "rgb(58, 58, 58)";
    document.body.style.userSelect = "";
    document.body.style.cursor = "";
    d.el = undefined;
  });
})();
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.handle {
  cursor: e-resize;
  width: 4px;
  background: #424242;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">wer</div>
  <div class="handle">|</div>
  <div class="div2">sdf</div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
d.div1.style.width = document.body.scrollWidth - e.clientX
```

and

```
d.div1.style.width = d.div1.offsetWidth + (e.clientX - d.mouseStartX - d.elStartX)
```

for width formula in `mousemove` event listener but neither worked.

Comment: basically you want two divs to be resized in width right? using handlebar

Comment: @Supercool.yes both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the offsetWidth is causing to double its pace. if you get its value once at the beginning as in;

```js
(function () {
  const d = {};
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    const container = e.target.closest(".container");
    if (container != null && e.target.classList.contains("handle")) {
      d.el = container;
      d.div1 = container.children[0];
      d.handle = container.children[1];
      d.div2 = container.children[2];
      d.mouseStartX = e.clientX;
      d.elStartX = d.el.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      d.handle.style.background = "rgb(100, 100, 100)";
      document.body.style.userSelect = "none";
      document.body.style.cursor = "e-resize";
    }
  });
  var ofs = null
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    if (d.el === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    if(ofs === null){
      ofs = d.div1.offsetWidth
    }
    d.div1.style.width =
      ofs + (e.clientX - d.mouseStartX) + "px";
  });
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    if (d.el === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    d.handle.style.background = "rgb(58, 58, 58)";
    document.body.style.userSelect = "";
    document.body.style.cursor = "";
    d.el = undefined;
  });
})();
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.handle {
  cursor: e-resize;
  width: 4px;
  background: #424242;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">wer</div>
  <div class="handle">|</div>
  <div class="div2">sdf</div>
</div>
```

would move with same pace.